# Random password generation with conditions

Tags: algorithm, passwords, generator

I'm working on a *random password generator* to create passwords that meet certain conditions including, but not necessarily limited to:

- *minimum length:* has to contain at least 8 characters
- *lower case letters:* has to contain lower case letters (chosen from a set to avoid problems of having characters that can be mistaken as numbers)
- *upper case letters:* has to contain upper case letters (again, chosen from a set)
- *digits:* has to contain numbers

What would be the best algorithmic approach to ensure that the generated password meets all these?

I'm not looking for a complete solution, I only need a few good ideas and guidelines.

Comment: http://www.texamples.com/how-to-generate-random-passwords-in-java/ this might help

Comment: not sure that this is a good idea. Imposing restrictions, like "2+" digits, potentially makes the password less "random", rather than more random/better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) randomly generate number L which will be the exact length of your password. Namely, generate is so that it is greater than 8 
2) randomly generate a number LL which will be the number of lowercase letters. LC must be in range [1..L-2] 
3) randomly generate number LU for uppercase. Must be in range [1..L-LL-1] 
4) LD = L-LL-LU number of uppercase digits 
5) randomly generate LL lowercase letters, LU uppercase letters, and LD digits and keep them in a list(array) 
6) Shuffle the array randomly

hth

Comment: +1 I'll add that a good shuffling is not-trivial :-) This is a link to a good algorithm with pseudocode http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: @xantos: Or, if using C++, we can use `std::random_shuffle()` method :)

Comment: I like it.  But why not just fix L at 8?.  It's the *easiest* length to remember while still satisfying the requirements.

Comment: There is some complexity hidden behind "randomly generate". If you use uniform random numbers, the generated passwords will not be distributed uniformly across the entire set of passwords meeting the requirements. For example, in an 8-character password you'll get 2.25 digits on average, while with @dana's solution you'll get 1.69.

Answer (score 4):

- create a character array containing a - z, A - Z, 0 - 9 (minus any characters that might be confusing per the question)
- concatenate 8 randomly chosen characters from the array
- test the result to see if it satisfies the requirements
- if the requirements are not satisfied, start over

The algorithm should usually succeed on the first few iterations, and saves you from having to implement a shuffle algorithm.

Comment: Absolutely!  It also doesn't have hidden biases.  Its worth noting that this terminates very quickly with high probability (expected number of attempts before finding an acceptable solution is 1.4).  Silly that I didn't notice your solution when writing mine (the same solution, but I assumed the random function produced random bytes 0x00-0xFF and didn't bother to fix the range).

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to the precise construction proposed by Armen.  If you're conditions can be met with high probability then:

- get an infinite length random string (a stream)
- lazily filter for the acceptable characters (ex: upper case || lower case || digit)
- step a window of the desired length across the stream, accept when the window properties are OK.

In a lazy language this is about 6 lines of non-boilerplate code and doesn't require any shuffling.

EDIT: Yes, step a window as in the comments, not slide a window.  Thanks!

Comment: Slide a window or step a window? If you slide, you'll bias the distribution of passwords to favour less frequent character classes at the end. Say you want 2-character passwords. Digits are less frequent than letters, so a typical stream has looks like `abcd5efg...`. As you slide the window, you reject `ab`, `bc`, `cd`  and accept `d5`. The digit is more likely to appear in the second position because as soon as it slides into that position the password becomes acceptable.

Comment: Right, you shouldn't really slide a window, but test discrete chunks of the desirable length:  `loop input = let (s,r) = splitAt len input in if strProp s then s else loop r`.  Back of the envelop calculation says you should expect to test 1.4 possible passwords to get a valid one (for 8 characters, so generating a password consumes 47 random bytes on average).